# strange error when using printf and inet_ntoa to print ip address

Tags: c, linux, network-programming

```
struct in_addr a,b,c,d;
if(inet_aton ("10.0.0.1", &a)!=-1 );
    printf("a:%s\n", inet_ntoa(a));
if(inet_aton ("10.0.0.2", &b)!=-1 )
    printf("b:%s\n", inet_ntoa(b));
```

It's no problem to print the to IP address:

```
a:10.0.0.1
b:10.0.0.2
```

However I found that:

```
inet_aton ("10.0.0.3", &c);
inet_aton ("10.0.0.4", &d);
printf("c:%s %s\n", inet_ntoa(c), inet_ntoa(d));
printf("d:%s\n", inet_ntoa(d));
```

It prints:

```
c:10.0.0.3 d:10.0.0.3
d:10.0.0.4
```

The strange things is that it prints the wrong IP of `d` at this line:

```
printf("c:%s %s\n", inet_ntoa(c), inet_ntoa(d));
```

I don't know why!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The manual for `inet_ntoa` says:

> The string
>          is returned in a statically allocated buffer, which  subsequent  calls  will
>          overwrite.

You have two functions in `printf("c:%s %s\n", inet_ntoa(c), inet_ntoa(d));` that overwrite the same buffer.

Try `if (inet_ntoa(c) == inet_ntoa(d))`, you may be surprised by the result.